Circular Statistics - Looking at wind selectivity in shorebirds and want to select the correct statistical test
I completed my Masters degree looking at shorebird migration ecology, specifically looking at their behaviour during southbound migration. One component was looking at the conditions upon departure from the area. We wanted to determine if birds were being selective of optimal weather conditions (wind speed and direction) or not. To test wind selectivity, we ran separate Watson’s U2 tests for each species and year combinations with selected wind conditions (conditions upon departures) versus overall wind conditions (all available wind conditions present during the time birds were in the region). From Watson’s U2 test for homogeneity of means, we determined that selection of wind direction differed among species. In particular for one of my study species (Semipalmated Sandpipers (SESA)), it appears that wind conditions on departure were less variable, suggesting that they were more selective than other species (figure attached).
The results suggested that SESA were selective in both years. For 2021, this makes sense - they are departing most frequently with North-West winds (which would be optimal for their southbound migration) which is the opposite of the prevailing available winds. This also follows patterns of what other people found in the lab in previous years for this species. For 2022, from the Watson’s U2 test, it also suggests they are selective but it appears they are departing most often with the most prevailing winds (and not optimal conditions). My advisor suggested this may be showing up as ‘selective’ due to most birds departing with the south winds (except two). So a different type of selectivity than in 2021 – rather than selecting opposite winds than what is most available, they are showing selectivity due to the narrower breath of wind direction birds were departing with. Does anyone know what would be the most appropriate test to select to show selectivity in this case? Or any suggestions are welcome. I am not too familiar with circular statistics. Thanks in advance!
I tried using a Watson's U2 test to compare the wind conditions during departure of birds versus the overall available wind conditions in the region during the time birds were present. We have mixed feelings of our results as it appears in both years birds were being selective but for different reasons (one showing what we would expect, the other being birds were departing with winds of a narrower breadth). We want some advice to determine if the Watson's U2 test is the most appropriate in this case.
